# Settings for RTMP and AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, rtmp

Is there any extra code need for using rtmp with AS3.

I have the code like this. Is that enough for rtmp or any other code needed?

```
var strSource:String = "rtmp://myserver.com/file.flv";
var ncConnection = new NetConnection();
var nsStream = new NetStream(ncConnection);
nsStream.play(strSource);
```

Answer (score 3):

Playing RTMP streams needs to be done differently that progressive ones.

First you need to connect to the application, usually this is the base path but can sometimes be some folder up in case the RTMP server proposes different services.

You then need to listen to the `NetConnection.Connect.Success` event dispatched by the `NetConnection` event.

Once the NetConnection is connected you can create a `NetStream` upon it and thereafter play the stream.

Note that the argument passed to the play command should only be the name of the stream and not the full path. Normally you also need to remove the extension (depends on server and service). For H264 streams you may also need to prefix the stream id with "mp4:".

**Example :**

```
// rtmp://myserver.com/service/myVideo.flv

var service:String = "rtmp://myserver.com/service/";
var streamID:String = "myVideo"; // or mp4:myVideo for H264

var netConnection:NetConnection;
var netStream:NetStream;

netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.client = {onBWDone:onNetConnectionBWDone}; 
netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler); 
netConnection.connect(service); 

// NetConnection status handlers

function netStatusHandler( event:NetStatusEvent ):void
{
    if(event.info.code == NetConnection.Connect.Success)
    {
        netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
        netStream.client = {onMetaData:onMetaData, onPlayStatus :onPlayStatus};
        netStream.play(streamID);
    }
}

function onNetConnectionBWDone():void{}

// NetStream Status handlers

function onMetaData(o:Object):void{}
function onPlayStatus(o:Object):void{}
```

Comment: Does this pertain to a published realtime stream or just pre recorded stream?

Comment: This answer is 4 years old, but from the top of my mind real time and on-demand streams work pretty much the same way, at least in terms of setup and connection.

Comment: I am still looking in the reams of Adobe documents of how to achieve it so I hope you are right.